# Is there an algorithm to compute the Maximum Likelihood Estimator?

Tags: algorithms, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Define $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x):=\begin{cases} \frac{2x}{\theta}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{when}\,\,\,0<x\leq\theta \\
\frac{2(1-x)}{1-\theta},\;\;\;\text{when}\;\theta<x\leq 1 \end{cases}.$$

I need to write a pseudocode for an algorithm that computes the MLE for $\theta$. I am searching the internet, but couldn't find a clear description of such algorithm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Iterative_procedures

Comment: i have seen this page but it is still not clear to me how to apply those algorithms to my function